# Gitlab: approved merge request still showing a messaged that need approval to be merged

Tags: gitlab

In a project I'm collaborating in GitLab one my MR is approved but GitLab still showing that

[image: Screenshot]

Cannot solve this issue with that is saying need to be approved but is already approved.

I already tried with the colleagues:

- asked other colleagues to approve
- Revoked and approved again

No success and there is no clue about it.
Seems a bug of Gitlab maybe.

Comment: Has someone from that `Default` group approved it?

Comment: Yes different people tried to approve but no change

Answer (score 0):

Decided to answer as was resolved and explain the issue.
The issue seems was a permission sort of a bug.
The administrator of the repo group had to reset the permissions to default and reapply it from beginning.
Then I was able to merge and continue using it.
Seems the issue affected varipus collaborators and the administrator contacted the Gitlab support about this issue.
For now worked resetting and applying again the same permissions.
However, strange issue happen.